# How does the Axiom of Foundation prevent an infinitely descending membership sequence?

Tags: set-theory

According to Wolfram, the axiom of foundation is equivalent to, ""A set contains no infinitely descending (membership) sequence". Why is this true?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_regularity#No_infinite_descending_sequence_of_sets_exists

Comment: The range of an infinite descending membership sequence would be a nonempty set with no $\in$-minimal member. (The converse implication involves using the axiom of choice, or at least the axiom of dependent choice.)